$G/P$ is isomorphic to $C_4 \times C_4$
$G$ is the group of matrices
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
0 & c
\end{pmatrix}
where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z}/5$ with $a, c \neq 0$.
This is a group of order $80$ with one (normal) $5$-Sylow subgroup: let's call it $P$. I am told that $ G/P \cong C_4 \times C_4$, but I have no idea why.
I've found that $P$ is the subgroup generated by
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
but this may be unnecessary.

$P$ has order $5$, how can it not be cyclic?

$G/P$ is not cyclic, sorry.

Oh, no problem.

Your group is the Borel subgroup of $GL(2,p)$ for $p=5$. There is a general result, saying that $B\cong C_p\rtimes (C_{p-1}\times C_{p-1})$. This gives your claim. See also here.
We have $B=U \rtimes T$, where $T$ is the subgroup of diagonal matrices in it. Taking $B/U$, where $U$ coincides with the $p$-Sylow subgroup, we obtain
$T$, the diagonal subgroup, which obviously is isomorphic to $C_{p-1}\times C_{p-1}$.
